# Why is mapping an object PK breaking ExpressMapper?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, generics, primary-key, express-mapper

Trying to implement a generic repository based on [an article by Chris Pratt](https://cpratt.co/generic-entity-base-class/) that uses `object` as the `Id` (PK).

All is good, until I tried to `.Map()`one of these objects with [ExpressMapper](http://www.expressmapper.org/).

More code below.  But essentially, when I try and do this:

```
var dataModel = postedModel.Map(new ExampleDataModel());
```

It gives me:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

When I change the `Id` property of `ExampleDataModel` to a `string` or `int` it works fine.

I've googled around. I don't see anything obvious, but I am a bit out of my depth. I'd like to know:

- What is causing this?
- Can I work round it somehow?

I'd like to continue using the object PK and ExpressMapper if possible because they're both suiting my project just fine.

---

```
public interface IDataModel
{
    object Id { get; }  
}

public interface IDataModel<PKT> : IDataModel
{
    new PKT Id { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DataModel<PKT> : IDataModel<PKT>
{
    public PKT Id { get; set; }
    object IDataModel.Id
    {
        get { return this.Id; }
    }
}



public class ExampleDataModel : 
    DataModel<string>, 
    IDataModel<string>
{
     public virtual string SomeProperty{ get; set; }

    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when you are doing `new ExampleDataModel()`, You are trying to initalize an instance of `ExampleDataModel` with parameterless constructor, but looking at your class, you don't have one, that's why you are getting

`No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`

You should add one parameterless constructor,
which looks like this

```
ExampleDataModel()
{
//init object 
}
```

though I am not sure how you want to init your object so I am not sure how your constructor should be.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay in getting back.  I don't think that is the problem on this occasion. My understanding is that C# adds a default parameterless constructor to objects unless one with parameters is specified. Nor does it explain how changing the Id property to `string` fixes the problem I'm seing.

Answer (score 2):

Change your ExampleDataModel class, I don't see the Id property, How you return `this.Id` there is not any reference for that, also you need a string Id property that `IDataModel<string>` force you I hope this help:

```
 public class ExampleDataModel : IDataModel, IDataModel<string>
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        object IDataModel.Id
        {
            get { return this.Id; }
        }

        public virtual string SomeProperty { get; set; }



        // etc.
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm so sorry, I had a killer typo in there.  `ExampleDataModel` inherits from `DataModel<string>`.  (I had put `IDataModel` instead of `DataModel<string>`.)  Therefore it should inherit the Id property from that.

Comment: I'm awarding you the bounty as it's a perfectly correct answer given the code as it was first presented.  If you have any suggestions regarding the updated code (in the question) I'd really appreciate it.